# Prolog: How to create an empty list

Tags: prolog

I am trying to "return" (for lack of a better word) an empty list in Prolog.

I have this:
`fibonacci(0, X) :- X is [].`

But when I do this:
`fibonacci(0, X).`

I am receiving this error as a result:
`ERROR: Type error: 'evaluable' expected, found '[]' (an empty_list)`

Comment: `X = []` instead

Comment: Simply: `fibonacci(0, []).`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a user who commented, using `X = [].` instead of `X is [].` worked.

Comment: You are allowed to answer your own question, though you won't earn any reputation for doing so. If this is the best [onlly] answer, feel free to accept it as such.